# How to reference element in a jQuery function's callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

Let's say I have a jQuery function like this:

```
$.fn.foo = function(param, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(params);
    }
}
```

and then when calling the function on an element like:

```
$('table tr').foo(bar, function(param) {
    console.log($(this)); // this needs to reference 'table tr'
});
```

In cases like this, I've noticed that `this` references the window. How would you reference the element that the function is being called on without passing it as an argument inside the callback?

Comment: To be honest this seems like a strange approach for a plugin method. What is your specific use case?

Comment: I wanted to submit the closest form when a `table tr` is double clicked, or if there's no form, just a button, to be able to specify in callback @charlietfl

Comment: Ok...just need to realize that you won't be able to isolate specific row instances doing it this way since `this` inside the plugin is jQuery object with all rows in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `call()` to set the scope of the function you invoke.

Also note that your `$.fn.foo` function definition requires two arguments, not one. I used the first one as the classname to apply to the element in this example.

```js
$.fn.foo = function(params, callback) {
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback.call(this, params);
  }
}

$('table tr').foo('foo', function(classname) {
  $(this).addClass(classname);
});
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```